# Why is this timer working and not working?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I made a java timer
everything works when all the code is in one file and separated.
When I start doing anything about it
create a separate js file and move the java code there
and even when i try to insert it inside php nawiada
in both cases it stops working
how is it like here it works and it's great.
but i want js in js file then it stops working,
I think it is about "'these elements but I don't know, I'll tire of the timer, best regards

```
var secs = 0;
var element = "czas"; 
var T = null;
function count(id)
{
    temp = secs;
    if(secs > 0)
    {
        result = Math.floor(temp) + "  ";
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = result;
        secs--;
    }
    else
    {
        document.location="/"
        clearInterval(T);
    }
}
function counter(seconds)
{
    secs = seconds;
    T = window.setInterval("count()", 1000);
}


echo
    '<div id="czas"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">counter(60);</script>'
;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you posted the code that *does* work?

Comment: yes, but when I try to put it in a separate .js file, TIMER stops working, REAL MADNESS

Comment: So... you want us to diagnose the non-working code?

Comment: helped me, because the code works, you can check it, but it must be in one file and separated <? php?> <javascript> </javascript> <? php?>
when I want to put java code into php code or make a .js file and move the javascript code there, it stops working, I have been struggling with it for a long time, I don't know what is, it works, but separately, it didn't work, I need help

Comment: It might make sense to post what *doesn't* work rather than what does.

Comment: sorry for my senselessness

Comment: but there is some little visible error in this that may help one person in the future

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244450/discussion-between-dervil-and-dave-newton).